# Set sciTE as default crontab editor

Tags: ubuntu, text-editors, crontab

I am trying to set `sciTE` as my default text editor, but when I run the commands below it errors.  Is it possible to use `sciTE` as default editor in `Ubuntu Mate`?  And how would I achieve such?

```
test@ubuntumate:~$ export EDITOR=sciTE
test@ubuntumate:~$ crontab -export
no crontab for test - using an empty one
/bin/sh: 1: sciTE: not found
crontab: "sciTE" exited with status 127
```